# An identity for Weierstrass elliptic functions evaluation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, elliptic-curves, elliptic-functions

Let $\wp(z), \zeta(z)$ and $\sigma(z)$ be the Weierstrass $\wp$, zeta and sigma functions associated to the ODE:
$$\wp'(z)^2 = 4(\wp(z)-e_1)(\wp(z)-e_2)(\wp(z)-e_3)$$
and we assume $e_1=\frac{2-c}3>e_2=\frac{2c-1}3>e_3=-\frac{1+c}3$ are all real roots, for small $c>0$.

Also, denote $\wp(\omega_1)=e_1, \wp(\omega_2)=e_3, \wp(\omega_3)=e_2$ and $\omega_3=\omega_1+\omega_2$. Further, let $\eta_1=\zeta(\omega_1)$ and $\eta_2=\zeta(\omega_2)$.

I need the below formula, so I would like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is this identity true?
> $$\wp(\omega_3)-\wp(\omega_2)=\frac{e^{2\eta_2\omega_2}}{\sigma(\omega_2)^4}.$$

Comment: If you multiply $\omega_j$ on $k>0$, then the LHS will be multiplied on $k^{-2}$ while the RHS will be multiplied on $k^{-4}$. So this cannot be true.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: you've a reasonable point. However, numerical evidence insists that the equation holds.

Comment: If you agree that my argument is valid, there must be a mistake or some implicit assumption in your computation. Just compute everything for $2\omega_1$ and $2\omega_2$.

Comment: I see exactly where actually. Thank you. The issue is fixed now, I hope. It has become a 1-parameter problem than 3.

Comment: You did not fix the formula in your question.

Comment: What am I missing now?

Comment: You did not change the formula in your question. So my objection to this formula remains.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Alexandre Eremenko's valuable questions on the earlier formulation of the problem. Now, after fixing the lacking information, I was actually able to prove what I asked about. Hope this saves people any more time.

We need two identities
$$\wp(u)-\wp(v)=-\frac{\sigma(u+v)\sigma(u-v)}{\sigma(u)^2\sigma(v)^2}, \tag 1$$
and also that
$$\sigma(z+2w_j)=-e^{2\eta_j(z+\omega_j)}\sigma(z) \tag 2$$
to find
\begin{align} \wp(\omega_3)-\wp(\omega_2)
&=-\frac{\sigma(\omega_1+2\omega_2)\sigma(\omega_1)}{\sigma(\omega_3)^2\sigma(\omega_2)^2}
=\frac{\sigma(\omega_1)^2e^{2\eta_2\omega_3}}{\sigma(\omega_3)^2\sigma(\omega_2)^2}.
\end{align}
That means, our task at hand (Q) boils down to
$$\sigma(\omega_3)=e^{\eta_2\omega_1}\sigma(\omega_1)\sigma(\omega_2). \tag 3$$
To this end, equation (2) implies that $\sigma(\omega_1+\omega_2)=-e^{2\eta_2\omega_1}\sigma(\omega_1-\omega_2)$ while
equation (1) offers
\begin{align}
1&=e_1-e_3=\wp(\omega_1)-\wp(\omega_2)=
-\frac{\sigma(\omega_1-\omega_2)}{\sigma(\omega_1)\sigma(\omega_2)}\cdot \frac{\sigma(\omega_1+\omega_2)}{\sigma(\omega_1)\sigma(\omega_2)}
=e^{-2\eta_2\omega_1}\cdot \frac{\sigma(\omega_1+\omega_2)^2}{\sigma(\omega_1)^2\sigma(\omega_2)^2}. \end{align}
A simple rearrangement verifies the identity in (3).

Comment: In your last equation you have $e_1-e_3 = \wp(\omega_1)-\wp(\omega_2)$ which has a typo.

Comment: Did you check my connecting definition between the $e$'s and $\omega$''?

Comment: Okay, I did now. But why did you define $\wp(\omega_1)=e_1$ ,$ \wp(\omega_2)=e_3,$ $\wp(\omega_3)=e_2$ which swaps $e_2$ and $e_3$? It is confusing and easily overlooked since it is not the usual definitions.

Comment: @Somos: I don't blame you. The literature is so mush clattered with different notations and definitions that I was frustrated as well. Sorry about that.